# Subir un archivo sin postback ni dar clic a un boton

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema de antemano gracias.

Mi objetivo es subir un archivo a una carpeta de mi proyecto sin que la pagina realice un postback ni dar clic a un botón.

Estoy usando un archivo externo de tipo JScript1.js que ya lo referencie en mi pagina, tambien estoy usando un Generic Handler que llame Guardar_Archivos.ashx.

Espero me puedan ayudar o decirme que estoy haciendo mal ya que aun no he podido subir el archivo a la carpeta de mi proyecto.

Gracias.

```js
// Este es mi codigo de mi archivo Guardar_Archivo.js

$("#btnSubir").on("change", function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
  $(this).siblings("#lblArchivo").addClass("selected").html(fileName);


    if (fileupload.value != '') {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/scriptConsultas/Guardar_Archivos.ashx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function() {
                alert("Archivo subido con exito");                
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
      
         <label id="lblArchivo" class="custom-file-label"> 
         <input id="btnSubir" type="file" name="btnSubir" class="custom-file" accept=".xlsx" />                    </label> 
                  
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el código de mi Generic Handler

```
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {

            HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string folderPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Archivos/" + fileName);

            postedFile.SaveAs(folderPath);

            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                new
                {
                    name = fileName
                });
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
            context.Response.Write(json);
            context.Response.End();

        }

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero cual es el error, no se ejecuta el onchage,  la llamada a tu handler llega vacio, error al guardar en la carpeta? Te invito a que des un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), para que te des una idea de como preguntar.

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate no me muestra ningún error en consola y al abrir la carpeta donde lo quiero guardar esta vacía. En conclusión el archivo no se esta enviando.

Comment: Que tipo de aplicacion estas creando un handler casi no se usa.

Comment: @MiguelZarate utilizo asp.net webForms y c# con visual studio 2008.

Comment: Es un proyecto nuevo puedes descargar vs2019 preview y realizarlo con herramientas mas actuales, esto para que tu aplicacion tenga mas tiempo de vida.

Comment: Por razones de seguridad NO puedes usar JS para subir un archivo sin interacción del usuario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014587/file-upload-with-javascript-without-user-intervention